# Kineticjs dragBoundFunc scale handle after rotation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have scale handles that can let you scale the object.
The handles in the corners have `dragbehavior = 0` the upper and bottom `1` and the left and right `2`.

```
dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {

            if(dragbehavior == 0) {var posx = pos.x; var posy = pos.y;}
            if(dragbehavior == 1) {var posx = this.getAbsolutePosition().x; var posy = pos.y;}
            if(dragbehavior == 2) {var posx = posx; var posy = this.getAbsolutePosition().y;}
              return {
                x: posx,
                y: posy
              }
          },
```

This works perfectly and when I rotate a object then the corner does still fine, but the handlers on the side are acting strangely after rotation. I know I need some rotate translation (sin/cos) but I don't know how to implement it. This is because most examples uses some orientation from the object itself you want to rotate, but this is with coordinates of the stage.

[image]
[image]

My mouse is at the arrow but the the rect is larger and the scale handle is not on the rect place. If I try to do the cursor at the end of the rect the rect stretches acros the whole screen.

[image]

Comment: do you have a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the rotation applied on a group containing the shape and the handlers ?

Comment: it is applied to group thats containing: shape, scalehandlers and rotation handle